# After approval of revision of charges using the revise api of Paypal, The subscription is not giving updated information

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using paypal rest apis to manage subscriptions and payments. The scenario is as follwoing:

1. User subscribes to monthly plan e.g 1st Jan.
2. In the middle of the month(15th jan), the user decides to upgrade to the yearly plan.( I use the revise api of paypal to change users plan. I redirect the user to the approval link. The user approves it and is redirected to "return_url"). By default the users yearly plan will be activated on 1st of feb.
3. I fetch the subscription details for that subscription id, and it still has the old information i.e (next_billing_time) is still the same(the 1st of next month). Shouldn't the next billing time be next year since the user has already paid for the (remaining 15 days + 1 year)?

I am using the Sandbox environment for all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user will be billed for the new subscription price at the next billing cycle, which is in 15 days. It will be 1 year before they are billed again.

This information is communicated during the approval.